# Is it safe to browse Reddit's NSFW with Tor in JAPAN?

Tags: anonymity, security, censorship

More specifically, my ISP is NTT Open Computer Network and I am currently using the internet in my dorm, which is technically off-campus. I really have NO IDEA what restrictions there are in regards to NSFW stuff (nothing illegal, just the typical stuff).

Will Tor prevent my ISP from knowing that I am browsing NSFW stuff? I don't want to get in trouble, since my Internet might still be considered "school internet".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Tor will hide your browsing from your ISP, although it might be better to ask your school administrators if pornography is allowed -as Tor might be too slow for you. Usually VPN's are much more fitting in cases like this.

Comment: Well, slowness isn't much of an issue for me, I guess, since I don't really watch vids, anyway. It's more for Reddit's NSFW sections. Also, I'd feel kinda embarrassed to ask school admins about pornography. As for VPN, I am definitely considering it, once I figure all my finances out.

Comment: @Rilakkuma Your ISP will be able to know you Tor. They may have a anti-Tor kinda policy.